# CORS policy issue with Spring Boot microservice and Angular frontend

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, deployment

I'm building a web application with an Angular frontend and multiple Spring Boot microservices on the backend. I'm currently facing a CORS policy issue when trying to send a POST request from my Angular app to one of my Spring Boot microservices.
The error message I'm getting in the browser console is:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/publications/new' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I have added the @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowCredentials = "true") annotation to the controllers in my microservices to allow cross-origin requests from my Angular app, but I'm still getting the error.

Here is the code for the controller in my publication-service microservice:

```
    `@RestController
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowCredentials = "true")
    @RequestMapping("/publications")
    public class PublicationController {

         @Autowired
         private PublicationService publicationService;

    @PostMapping("/new")
    public ResponseEntity<Publication> createPublication(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,       @RequestParam("content") String content ,@RequestParam("username") String username) throws     IOException {
        Publication publication = new Publication();
        publication.setContent(content);
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(publicationService.createPublication(publication, file),   responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    }      `
```

In the angular part i have this HTTP interceptor :

```
`    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      withCredentials: true,
    });

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}

export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpRequestInterceptor, multi: true },
     ];`
```

i also modified the application.properties of my microservice like this :

```
server.port=8082
spring.application.name=publication-service
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone= http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/jeee?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=66pasS..
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#pour ouvrir canal de connexion
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Enable CORS
spring.mvc.cors.allow-credentials=true
spring.mvc.cors.allowed-origins=http://localhost:4200
spring.mvc.cors.allowed-methods=GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
spring.mvc.cors.allowed-headers=*
```

Comment: Do you have a security config class that extends to WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter? or at least a class that has filterchain method that is annotated with @Bean?

Comment: Hi Luigi, currently i have not. I tried both yesterday but neither of them solved the issue. So i deleted them both from my microservice.

Comment: try adding this to your configure or filterchain method  " http.cors().and().csrf().disable();"

Comment: I think a better solution is to implement a gateway (spring cloud gateway for example) which will be the only entry point to your backend services and add the CORS policies on the level of the gateway

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to fix the CORS Policy

1. Create CORS Configurer in the backend like below :

   @Bean
   public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {

   ```
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                if (allowedOrigins != null && allowedOrigins.length > 0) {
                    registry.addMapping("/**").allowCredentials(true).allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins).allowedMethods("GET", "POST","PUT", "DELETE");
                }
            }
        };
    }
   ```

In your application.properties file, you can mention which host where it calls from
something like this

```
cors.allowed_from= http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:3000,  http://localhost:9000/api/swagger-ui.html#/
```

2. Create a proxy file called (proxy.conf.json) in UI and include that in angular.json like below:

proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://dev.mcc.api.xxx.com",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
  }
```

angular.json:

"serve": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json",